# how to check wether a user login for firsr time or not in django so i can rediect him to another page then usual

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-signals

i want user to redirect to a from page where he has to submit detail if he is logged in site for first time or if a already a user for sometime and logged in before he will redirect to normal home page so any idea how can i achieve that in django

here is my login views

```
def my_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            remember_me = form.cleaned_data['remember_me']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                if not remember_me:
                    request.session.set_expiry(0)
                    return redirect('accounts:home')
                else:
                    request.session.set_expiry(1209600)
                    return redirect('accounts:home')
            else:
                return redirect('accounts:login')
        else:
            return redirect('accounts:register')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, "login.html", {'form': form})
```

i want user to redirect to this form if he is logging in site for first time

```
@login_required
def add_address(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Addressform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:home')
    else:
        form = Addressform()
    return render(request, 'add_address.html', {'form': form})
```

other wise then to normal home page
i have also seen a same stackoverflow question where the are using signals but i dont really get how to implement in my code where session expiry is decided by user

Comment: After the `registration process` you can redirect to the `page` you want and after login you can redirect to home page.

Comment: you can check the user's last_login. user_instance.last_login. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_login